# selecting into a variable in a subquery in an insert - syntax prob or what?

Tags: mysql, insert, subquery, syntax-error

I constructed an insert that does a number of operations to calculate the values that are to be inserted.  The first of the values is, however, simply a scalar, an unvarying id that is to be associated with all the records/fields that are to be calculated then inserted.  That scalar value is taken from a table other than the one from which all the rest of the values are extracted or calculated.

That value should be assigned to a variable, too, and I thought it should be possible to do so in the select expression of the insert.  I've not been able to do it and I can't figure out where I'm going wrong, if it's my syntax that's in error or if I'm trying to do something illegal.  When I do this assignment in a separate statement, it works.  It's just when I combine the statements, as follows:

This works fine (I omitted most of the calcs):

```
select id into @univ_num from u order by id desc limit 1;
insert into um (id_universe, pid, $vol)
   select @univ_num, pid, cv/@univ_len as $vol
     from (select pid as pid, close as close, vol as vol, sum(d.close * d.vol) as cv
       from ... -- from the debug_data_1 table
         where... ) x;
```

But this does not:

```
insert into um (id_universe, pid, $vol)
select (select id into @univ_num from u order by id desc limit 1), pid, 
cv/@univ_len as $vol...from..where..etc...
```

The parser doesn't like the 'into':

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual...
for the right syntax to use near 'into @univ_num from u order by id desc limit 1), pid, cv/@univ_len as $vol' at line 2
```

The parser doesn't mind it without the 'into'; Without the 'into @univ_num', the subquery and the query all together is fine, i.e.,

```
insert into um (id_universe, pid, $vol)
select (select id from u order by id desc limit 1), pid, cv/@univ_len as $vol
```

is fine.  TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't seen it in the MySQL docs, but, this form works, with the assignment operator (line 3):

```
select @univ_num, pid, cv/@univ_len as $vol
 from
   (select  @univ_num := (select id from univ_members order by id desc limit 1) a) b,
   (select pid as pid, close as close, vol as vol, sum(d.close * d.vol) as cv
   from ... -- from the debug_data_1 table
     where... ) x;
```